# The third column of cv2.getRotationMatrix2D

Tags: python, opencv, data-augmentation

I have been learning how to rotate images without cropping recently. But I am slightly confused with the third column of cv2's getRotationMatrix2D. It returns a matrix of size 2 by 3.

[image]

Although my code is working based off [Rotate an image without cropping in OpenCV in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c) and [Python 2.7.3 + OpenCV 2.4 after rotation window doesn't fit Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764575/python-2-7-3-opencv-2-4-after-rotation-window-doesnt-fit-image), I would be glad and keen to know what exactly the third column of this transformation matrix does.

Comment: In this case, you are asking about the theory? [This](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html#theory) may be helpful

Comment: pure rotation is around the position (0,0) if you want to rotate around another center you basically first translate the image, rotate around rhe new (0,0) and translate back. You can combine all those transformation steps to a single one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Yunus for the documentation link. According to the documentation

> The transformation maps the rotation center to itself. If this is not the target, adjust the shift.

which means M_rotation * vector_of_rotation_center = vector_of_rotation_center and the expression in the documentation is set such that the equation holds.

The first two columns in the rotation matrix specifies the rotation transformation and scaling transformation; the third column is used to specify the translation transformation.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this too, translation of what? You only rotate? Or are all pixels translated by a common value in rototation?